# Return statement not sending value to display

Tags: java, android

My return statement is not working while all values up until the get statement (i.e. the set, variables, etc) are working, if forced to a value the display works.

```
  if (Pasta.isChecked() && Pork.isChecked() && Tomato.isChecked() && Carrots.isChecked() && TomatoPaste.isChecked()) {
                       // RecipeCodes recipe1 = new RecipeCodes();
                        //recipe1.setRecipeCode(1);
                        setRecipeCode(1);
                        getRecipecode();
                        //Recipecode = 1;
                        Log.i("INTERNAL CHECK", "RCODE ~" + Recipecode);
                        break;

 public void setRecipeCode(int C) {
    Recipecode = C;
    Log.i("SETRECIPECODETEST", "RECIPE CODE ~ " + Recipecode);
}


public int getRecipecode(){
   return Recipecode;
}
```

Here is my code for the class that displays based on the "RecipeCode" variable

```
    Recipes temp = new Recipes();
    RecipeCodes RDisplay = new RecipeCodes();
    //temp.getRecipeCode();

    if(temp.getRecipecode() == 1){
        RDesc.setText("Italiano Sausage");
        //Log.i("WITHINIF","RCODE INTERNAL ~ " + temp.getRecipeCode());
    } else {
        RDesc.setText("test");
        //Log.i("TEST","RCODE WITHIN DISPLAY ~ " + RDisplay.getRecipeCode());
    }
```

(I've done a lot of editing and commenting out of lines so if there's minor syntax errors my bad).

Comment: Can you explain in detail by adding complete code which return statement is not working and in what scenario ?

Comment: what is your desired result?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
class Recipe {
    private int recipecode;

    public void setRecipeCode(int c) {
        recipecode = c;
    }

    public int getRecipecode() {
        return recipecode;
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Recipe temp = new Recipe();
        temp.setRecipeCode(1);
        System.out.println(temp.getRecipecode());
    }
}
```